# How to use c++ swap function?

Tags: c++

When I write like this `swap(a,b);` it is ok.

When I write like this `swap(&c[0],&d[0]);` there is a error.
Somebody can tell me why?

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main(void){
    int *a;
    int *b;
    int c[]={1,2};
    int d[]={3,4};
    a=&c[0];
    b=&d[0];
    swap(a,b);// it is ok
    //swap(&c[0],&d[0]);// it is error why
    cout<<a[0]<<" "<<b[0]<<endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: because you should write `swap(c[0],d[0]);`, `&c[0]` and `&d[0]` are rvalues, but you can swap lvalues only

Comment: Thank you. I confused arrays and pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `swap(&c[0],&d[0])` with `swap(c[0], d[0])`.

`&c[0]` and `&d[0]` are rvalues (temporary objects of type `int*`), but you can swap lvalues only.

You're able to `swap(a, b)` because `a` and `b` are lvalues, `a` after swap will be pointing to `d[0]` and `b` to `c[0]`, `swap(a, b)` wouldn't swap values in array, this is a difference in behaviour (thanks to M.M's comment with a notice).

Comment: note that `swap(c[0], d[0])` has different behaviour to `swap(a,b)`

Answer (score 1):

user3365922 is correct on the syntax if you wish to swap the contents of c[0] and d[0].

Just to add on because you code sample is a bit weird. 
std::swap(a,b) in your code isn't actually swapping the contents c[0] and d[0]. It's swapping the pointers a & b. I mention this because it looks like you replaced the std::swap(&c[0], &d[0]) with std::swap(a,b)--which isn't actually equivalent (this is an assumption, my bad if they weren't meant to be equivalent).

I'm not totally sure what your goal is, but std::swap(c[0], d[0]) will achieve swapping the first entry of c with the first entry of d (leaving the second entry as-is). If you actually wanted to swap the contents of arrays entirely in the example above, you could also do std::swap(c, d).

Answer (score 0):

swap function

```
  template <class T> void swap ( T& a, T& b )
  {
     T c(a); a=b; b=c;
  }
```

And  `a=&c[0]; b=&d[0];` after `swap(a,b);`

```
  a will pointing to d[0]
  b will pointing to c[0]
```

and here `swap(&c[0],&d[0]);` the prototype dose not match the current swap function.The required prototype is

```
  swap(int*,int*)
```

so there is no matching function to call so the compiler throws error.

Answer (score -1):

The arguments to `std::swap()` are two integer pointers, not two addresses of an array with an index.

For swapping normal singular `int` values you will have to use a pointer (call by reference), but for an array you could directly pass it (as base address of array is taken) for which you could have used `c[0],d[0]`. Using `&` to reference the array (i.e. using `&c[0],&d[0]`) with the function accepting a `int *` type would cause argument type mismatch, with your passed values being rvalues of type `int *`, which cannot be swapped. (whereas lvalues like `c,d` and `c[index],d[index]` can be swapped)

The error you recieved should be:

> main.cpp:12:13: error: no matching function for call to ‘swap(int*, int*)’
>        swap(&c[0],&d[0]);
>                        ^

This pertains to invalid initialization of a non-const reference of type `int*&` from an rvalue of type `int*`, which is included in the error message.

If what you want to consider as the parameters are indeed addresses of the arrays, this would be your function:

```cpp
void swap_array_elements(int a, int b, int arr[], int arr2[]) 
{
  int temp = arr[a];
  arr[a] = arr2[b];
  arr2[b] = temp;
}
```

Note that the first two arguments used here are indices of the two arrays passed respectively as the third and fourth argument. This will swap in between any two elements you require among the two arrays.
 
 *Example:*

```cpp
#include <iostream>
void swap_array_elements(int a, int b, int arr[], int arr2[]) 
{
  int temp = arr[a];
  arr[a] = arr2[b];
  arr2[b] = temp;
}
int main()
{ int array1[]={42,56}, array2[]={63,89};
  swap_array_elements(0,1,array1,array2); // swapping element with index 0 in array1 (42) with element with index 1 in array2 (89)
  std::cout<<array1[0]<<" "<<array2[1]; // 89 42
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your flashy equivalent method is vulnerable to overflow.

Comment: @Bathsheba Understood, with addition of `*a+*b` it does, I just wanted to highlight the use of integer pointers with different ways to implement the swap function calling them 'equivalents' in the sense they all accept `int *` type arguments. I should've just included the traditional swap with a temporary variable.