# Using swap function does not produce expected result

Tags: c++, swap

What am I doing wrong? I would like to understand how I could get the function to swap the numbers.

```
void findsmallest(int* a, int* b, int* c)
{

    if(a > b)
        swap(a, b);
    if(b > c)
        swap(b, c);
    if (a > c)
        swap(a, c);

}

int main()
{

    int a,b,c;
    int smallest, middle, last;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    findsmallest(a, b, c);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should change to an appropriate title, change to appropriate tags (which programming language?), format your code properly, and describe the problem in the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use c++ swap function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60984206/how-to-use-c-swap-function)

Comment: It's been years and years since I programmed in C++, but I believe you are swapping the pointers around rather than the values. So try to dereference the values, and then maybe it will work.

Comment: That code shouldn't even compile (since `findSmallest()` is called by passing three arguments of type `int`, and is specified to accept three pointers).   So it shouldn't produce any result.

Comment: Should "work" with `void findsmallest(int& a, int& b, int& c)`.

Comment: Change `if`-s like `if(*a > *b)`. You compare `a` and `b` values, not addresses.

Answer (score 0):

```
void findsmallest(int* a, int* b, int* c)
{
    if (*a > *b)
        swap(*a, *b);
    if (*a > *c)
        swap(*a, *c);
    if (*b > *c)
        swap(*b, *c);
}

int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    findsmallest(&a, &b, &c);
    return 0;
}
```

because swap use references, not pointers, then u must give an object, not pointer to object
the operand * depointered, operand & take a point of object

Comment: Why have you created a new answer instead of extending the existing one? If `*c` contains the smallest, it does not work (it would end in the middle). The variables `smallest`, `middle`, and `last` are unused, by the way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Sebastian, i just make worked code, dont correcting programm logic